# ALTER TABLE won't accept a series of operations

Tags: postgresql

According to the example from the PostgreSQL 12 [docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-altertable.html) it should be possible to make a series of operation within one ALTER TABLE command. But when I do the following it gives me a syntax error at the possition of the comma:

```
CREATE TABLE a (id INT, name TEXT);
ALTER TABLE a
    RENAME COLUMN id TO di,
    RENAME COLUMN name TO eman;
```

What is wrong here?

Comment: According to the documentation page you linked to, `RENAME COLUMN` is not among the actions that you can have many of.

Comment: Was it changed recently? Because I find some examples like this https://stackoverflow.com/a/25398701/5360898

Comment: Peoples on the internet are not always correct.

Comment: @yaugenka no, it wasn't changed recently.  Sometimes people give advice without testing it.

Comment: its strange that that answer was accepted and has a lot of votes up. thanks anyway.

Comment: @yaugenka: that answer does not combine two `rename` column options.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name But what it does do is still not allowed.  You can't combine a column rename with any other action, either.